# Integer Parsing From a Substring - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: vb.net, parsing, integer, substring, steam

long time no see. I'm trying to wrap up some code really quickly and I get an error of Input string was not in a correct format on the line Dim num2 As Integer = Integer.Parse(SteamID32.Substring(8, 9)). I don't think I've done anything wrong. And numbershere is actually numbers, just hiding my public ID.

```
    Dim SteamID32 As String = "STEAM_0:0:numbershere"

    Dim num1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(SteamID32.Substring(10))
    Dim num2 As Integer = Integer.Parse(SteamID32.Substring(8, 9))

    Dim UserID32 As Integer = (num1 * 2) + num2

    Label1.Text = "U:1:" + UserID32.ToString
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of last character index, you need to specify the length for second parameter of `Substring` :

```
Dim num2 As Integer = SteamID32.Substring(8, 1)  'num2 = 0'
```